# Saving file object using matplotlib savefig, creating tar file from multiple svg figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, tarfile

I have created multiple figures using python with matplotlib. PyQt5 is used as a backend to display the figures. I am saving the figures in svg format using savefig.

My problem is that I would like to create a single zip file containing all of the svg files. A simplified version of what I have is:

```
import matplotlib
figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure(dpi=72)
canvas = matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg.FigureCanvasQTAgg(figure)
axes = figure.add_axes((0.1, 0.15, 0.85, 0.8))
axes.plot(data)
# Do all of that three times to give me three separate figures
# (let's call them figure, figure1 and figure2)
```

Now I can save each figure using

```
figure.savefig(filename, format='svg')
figure1.savefig .....
```

But I would actually like to have something like

```
fileobject = figure.savefig(format='svg')
```

where I could use `tarfile` module to compress and store all `fileobject`s in a single archive. My current workaround is to save the files, read them and use those objects to create the tar file and deleting the originals afterwards. Having a more direct way to do this would be nice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a [buffered stream](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#buffered-streams) to save your file to. Something like:

```
import io

fileobject1 = io.BytesIO()
figure1.savefig(fileobject1, format='svg')

fileobject2 = io.BytesIO()
figure2.savefig(fileobject2, format='svg')
```

etc.